# A basic question about Equal

Tags: expression-test

Can someone explain me why the following evaluates to True?

```
Pi/2 == Pi/2.

(*True*)
```

Comment: Because `Pi == Pi`, `"/" == "/"` and  `2 == 2.` ?

Comment: `Equal` is an attempt to express a certain interpretation of the concept of mathematical equality. It does not operate like in other languages in that data types are not taken into account.

Comment: more obvious example: `Pi==3.14159265358975->True` while `Pi-3.14159265358975==0. ->False`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only difference is that 2 is an exact number and 2. is an approximate number. According to documentation:

> - Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered
>     equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits
>     (roughly their last two decimal digits).
> - For numbers below machine precision the required tolerance is reduced
>     in proportion to the precision of the numbers.
> - 2==2. gives True.

On the other hand 2 === 2. or Pi/2 === Pi/2. evaluate to False.

Comment: For those who wonder `===` is `SameQ[ ]`

Comment: returning `True` for approximately equal reals is one of those tidbits that really ought to not be hidden under "details" in the docs. ( I doubt few who get tripped by this actually look up `==` in the docs at all though )